# How can I bulk delete media and attachments using WP-CLI?

Tags: attachments, media, media-library, wp-cli

I'm trying to mass delete 4000 images in a wordpress website. WP itself sets the max to 999, which would work fine and take a few minutes to delete them via the backend. However, I get REQUEST URI TOO LARGE because the backend form uses GET instead of POST.

How can I use WP-CLI to perform the operation if it's possible and ensure the integrity of the WP database. In other words, I don't want to run an SQL command.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the WP-CLI documentation about [`wp post delete`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/post/delete/):

```
wp post delete --force $(wp post list --post_type='attachment' --format=ids)
```

See [`wp post list`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/post/list/) for additional information.

Comment: I get this: Warning: Posts of type 'attachment' do not support being sent to trash.
Please use the --force flag to skip trash and delete them permanently.

Comment: @Flimm it is becaus your probably miss the "--force" arg. It works as a charm otehrwise ;)